# How to pass ASP.NET Identity user credentials to WebRequest

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-identity, owin

I have a ASP.NET MVC web application with ASP.NET Identity authentication. I need to create a WebRequest in backend code in controller to call WebAPI method of different web application with ASP.NET Identity authentication.

So, how can I obtain current user credentials to pass it to HttpWebRequest?
I tried to get it through CreadentialsCache, but it is not initialized.

I am using Owin implementation to setup Identity authentication in my web applications.

Comment: Look into using bearer tokens. Make an initial request to authenticate the user, get the token and add it to the authorization header for subsequent requests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid you might be out of luck here. In default Identity configuration password is always stored as a salted hash. The only times password is available in memory is when user types it in a form and submits it - on password change or login actions.

But depending on your API you are working with - you might login there at the same time user logs into your application and get an auth-token to use later - similar to auth-cookie you get in MVC-app

Comment: I will check it. Thanks!

Comment: If I am loggining through external login I will not get user password (only token), but how can I use it to get token from WebAPI project?

Comment: You should be able to use the same token in WebAPI